# Unit tests for code accessing ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, active-directory, mocking

What's the best way to unit test an application accessing the ActiveDirectory and/or mock the dependencies to the AD?

All the required types such as `DirectorySearcher` and `DirectoryEntry` don't appear to be easily mockable.

We've got methods like `FindByUserName()` and would like to (unit) test them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they're not mockable (don't have MSDN at hand, so I can't really tell), you can always abstract them behind an `IDirectorySearcher` and `IDirectoryEntry` and mock these. With this approach you can simplify the API by tailoring it specifically to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'll try a few things out and I'll let you know what worked.

Comment: Won't it cause much code duplication? So far cannot imagine how you gonna do that. Let's say I have Web API controller method which works with DirectorySearcher. So, do I need to prepare UT method, executing the same logic, but using IDirectorySearcher?

Answer (score 2):

Is there no other possibility to use a leightweight directory server (ldap) like java developers do with Apache DS (http://directory.apache.org) in .NET?!

This would be a nice alternative.